# Row highlighting based on a value fetched from a database

Tags: php, mysql

Below I've shown my PHP code for showing rows of table, how can I highlight rows if `selected_val` is 1 in the table `selected_candidate`?

Below I have shown the query and the if / else loop I'm using. I'm getting the following warning: 'Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource'.

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
    {
        $i=0;
        while($data_set = mysql_fetch_array($result_set))
        {
            $i=0;
            echo "<div id=\"Message1[$i]\" class=\"box\">";
            echo "Country ={$data_set['ecountry']}<br/>";
            echo "State = {$data_set['estate']}<br/>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><input id=\"select_candi{$i}\" onclick=\"javascript:func(this.id,{$_SESSION['uid']})\" type=\"checkbox\" name=\"check_candi[]\" value=\"{$data_set['eid']}\"/></td>"; 
            echo "<td>{$data_set['ename']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$data_set['lname']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$data_set['ecell']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$data_set['eposition']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$data_set['eemail']}</td>";

            if($data_set['ecity']=='')
            {
                echo "<td>{$data_set['ecountry']}</td>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<td onmouseover=\"ShowText('Message1[$i]'); return true;\" onmouseout=\"HideText('Message1[$i]'); return true;\" href=\"javascript:ShowText('Message1')\">{$data_set['ecity']}</td>";
            }

            // echo "<td>{$data_set['ecountry']},{$data_set['estate']},{$data_set['ecity']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$qua}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$data_set['other_work1']} {$data_set['other_work2']}{$data_set['other_work3']}{$data_set['other_work4']} {$data_set['other_work5']} {$data_set['other_work6']} {$data_set['other_work7']} {$data_set['other_work8']} {$data_set['other_work9']} {$data_set['other_work10']}
                 {$data_set['other_work1e']} {$data_set['other_work2e']} {$data_set['other_work3e']} {$data_set['other_work4e']} {$data_set['other_work5e']} {$data_set['other_work6e']} {$data_set['other_work7e']} {$data_set['other_work8e']} {$data_set['other_work9e']} {$data_set['other_work10e']}
                </td>";
            echo "<td><a href=\"detailcv.php?id={$data_set['eid']}\" target=\"_blank\"><input  style=\" cursor:hand;width:40px\" class=\"button\" name=\"cv\" type=\"button\" value=\"C V\" /></a></td>";
            echo "</tr>";

            $i++;
        }
    }

?>
```

Query: in this I have fetched `selected_val`

```
$query = "SELECT emp.eid,ename,lname,ecell,eposition,eemail,ecountry,estate,ecity,prefcities,ca,cs,cwa,completed,persuing,other_work1,other_work2,other_work3,other_work4,other_work5,other_work6,other_work7,other_work8,sc.selected_val ";   
$query .= "FROM employee emp,selected_candidate sc";
```

If loop:

```
if($data_set['selected_val']=='1')
{
    echo "<script>$('#{$rowid}').css(\"background-color\",\"yellow\");</script>";
}

$rowid++;

selected_candidate Table


 eid  int(30)
    rid int(30)
    selected_val int(1)
```

`employee table also contains eid int(30)`

Thanks.

Comment: You need to give us some more context on this question. From the error you're receiving it looks like there could be any number of things going wrong. Maybe you've not selected a database in PHP.

Comment: initially i was getting values properly fetched but when i added 2nd table `selected_candidate` in query it gave me this result

Comment: Could you show the structure of your MySQL tables please?

Answer (score 0):

The error often means that you have a mistake in your query. To get more details on it, replace `mysql_query($query)` by `mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error())`.

It could be something like a syntax error or a mistyped column name.

Comment: i have this `$result_set = mysql_query($query);` ,how can i write `mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error())`

Comment: By simply replacing `mysql_query($query)` by `mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error())`. I.e., `$result_set = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: it is showing that there is some error on this line will you pls check syntax `$query .= "FROM employee emp,selected_candidate  sc";`

Comment: It's because your trying to select from 2 tables at once. You should select from your main table using from, then join other tables on using inner join and left join where appropriate.

Comment: can v continue it to chat?

Comment: Using tables like that is just fine. The problem is likely a typo. Have you verified that the names are spelled correctly? Otherwise, try encapsulating the names with backticks as such: ``$query .= "FROM `employee `emp`, `selected_candidate` `sc`";``

Comment: I checked but nothing is working,shall i edit above query with previously working query?